# How to stop py files from running when double-clicking them?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

What is the correct and most elegant way stop python files from running when double clicking them?
This happens since I installed [ms-python.python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)  tools  in VS code (on Win 10).
However, I run Python only in [CAD application scripting](https://wiki.mcneel.com/developer/python).
When double clicking a file I would like to open it in VS code for editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, right-click on a .py file and choose "open with ...". Select the VS Code editor and check "Always use this app to open .py files".

Very similar in Linux, except that the option is in Properties ... "Open With"

Answer (score 1):

Can you right click a .py file > Open with > Choose another app > Select Visual Studio Code and the checkbox for "Always use this app to open .py files"

Answer (score 1):

Right click, open with, chose another app and then you select VScode and tick the box